# How to replace/remove some part of a string

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a string in which i want to remove some part.

1) below is the string( Encrypted message)

@@**_/profiles/c3ed4acd-b3be-487e-81b4-a27643745d**^^____User1__@@@^^^ says hello to @@**_/profiles/d3ac3c5a-8a9f-4640-8563-127674d93e**^^____User2__@@@^^^

I want to get below 2 things from this

a) A string

@User1 says to @User2

2) A json object like

```
{
        "c3ed4acd-b3be-487e-81b4-a27643745d":"User1",
        "d3ac3c5a-8a9f-4640-8563-127674d93e":"User2"
}
```

First I tried to get string and used below approach using regex

I have tried it by doing like this

```
var str = "@@___/profiles/c3ed4acd-b3be-487e-81b4-a27643745d__^^____User1__@@@^^^ says to @@___/profiles/d3ac3c5a-8a9f-4640-8563-127674d93e__^^____User2__@@@^^^"
var rx = /(^@@___|,@@@^^^)/;  // start with @@___ and end with @@@^^^
var expectedString = str.replace(/(^@@___|,@@@^^^)/g, "");
console.log(expectedString);
```

But this is just replace first occurance of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some fundamental problems in your code

- you have to escape the `^` character as `\^`
- you don't even use your `rx` variable
- pipe character `|` means or, not start with and end with

try this:

```js
// a)
var str = "@@___/profiles/c3ed4acd-b3be-487e-81b4-a27643745d__^^____User1__@@@^^^ says to @@___/profiles/d3ac3c5a-8a9f-4640-8563-127674d93e__^^____User2__@@@^^^"
var rx = /@@___([^_]+)__\^\^____([^_]+)__@@@\^\^\^/g;  
var expectedString = str.replace(rx, "@$2");
console.log(expectedString);


// b)
var list = {};
while ((m = rx.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === rx.lastIndex) {
    rx.lastIndex++;
  }
  list[m[1]] = m[2];
}
console.log(list);
```